# Creating Dynamic Array inside of a class with an If statement if the storage is segmented

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I am wanting to create C++ program with a class inside of it that will contain a storage composed of one or multiple dynamic arrays for storing doubles and will state if the storage is segmented if there's multiple arrays. Where can I go from here?

```
class DynamicArray {

public:
    void addElemement(double num){

    }
    void removeElement(double num){

    }
    void segmentation(int x){

    }
    void merge(){

    }
    void print(){

    }

};   
int main(){

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @IlyasMimouni That question asks for a _segmentation fault_, I'm pretty sure that's not what the OP is talking about.

Comment: Not completely sure what you are after, but if you want the data structure inside your class to use more than one contiguous chunk of memory, look at std::deque. (STL). I am not sure if you easily can check how many chunks the deque has actually allocated, though... It may be useful to have the property of deque that growing the deque beyond a max capacity does not require re-allocating all memory used. EDIT: Checking nr chunks may be doable by wrapping the standard allocator for deque.

Comment: @ErikAlapää That sounds a little confusing but I am reading through the link that you've posted. Thanks! I'll let you know if it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

(Upgrading my comment to an answer, in case it fits the bill ;) )
http://cpp-tip-of-the-day.blogspot.se/2013/11/how-is-stddeque-implemented.html

Not completely sure what you are after, but if you want the data structure inside your class to use more than one contiguous chunk of memory, look at std::deque. (STL). I am not sure if you easily can check how many chunks the deque has actually allocated, though... It may be useful to have the property of deque that growing the deque beyond a max capacity does not require re-allocating all memory used. EDIT: Checking nr chunks may be doable by wrapping the standard allocator for deque

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you want to structure your storage. But as you are speaking of *storage segmentation*, I assume that you do not want to use a standard container but create your own low level structure.

Liminary remark: you did not spoke of what your class should *functionally* be: a set (only one copy of each value entered, what the `remove` method let imagine), a stack (always add new element at the end), an ordered set, using natural double comparisons or insertion order... so I will not give code, because each usage would get its implementation particularity.

The common implementation for non consecutive storage is a recursive tree. It is composed of *chunks* containing pointer to other chunks for non terminal (or non leaf) nodes and values (or pointer to values) for leaves. Those chunks have generally a fixed size. For example, it is (highly simplified) how files are implemented in a file system. If you give more details on what you actually w

Comment: @MRxBEYOND: if you give more details on what you actually want, I could try to give more precision on my answer :-)